# Why isn't an object type with a defined prop a subtype of an object type with an optional prop in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In Flow I can declare an object type with an optional prop such that an object with that prop defined satisfies it.

```
function getName(thing: {name?: string}): string {
  return thing.name || 'unknown';
}
getName({name: 'bob'}); // works
```

But if I declare an object type for the param before passing it, Flow logs an error.

```
const thing: {name: string} = {name: 'bob'};
getName(thing); // error
```

So why doesn't the type with the defined prop satisfy the type with the same prop as optional? How would I go about fixing up these annotations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare the type

```
function getName(thing: {name?: string}): string {
  return thing.name || 'unknown';
}
```

that means it would be typesafe for your function to do

```
function getName(thing: {name?: string}): string {
  thing.name = undefined;
  return "anything";
}
```

because you've said `name` is allowed to be `undefined`.

Given that,

```
const thing: {name: string} = {name: 'bob'};
getName(thing); // error
```

would break type safety the value wouldn't be a string anymore.

The solution here is to use [property variance](https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/). In your usecase, what this essentially means in your usecase is that you declare that your input `name` property` cannot be changed inside the function.

```
function getName(thing: { +name?: string }): string {
  return thing.name || 'unknown';
}
```

which so Flow knows that modifying `name` is not allowed. If it knows that, then it is safe to pass in an `{name: string}` object, which will allow your code to work.